# Spring boot admin client's status is shown down simetimes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I tried to use spring-boot-admin, but an issue made me confused.

I built two spring boot applications, one is the admin server, the other is the admin client. Fllowed [Spring Boot Admin Reference Guide](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.6/), i configed the reference properties, then admin server and client applications were both running successfully.

But after a moment, i found the status of admin client application is down, and in the console log infos were like:

```
2017-03-10 15:07:06.830  WARN 12960 --- [registrationTask1] d.c.b.a.services.ApplicationRegistrator: 
Failed to register application as Application [id=null, name=ERP Basic Management Module, managementUrl=http://PC-PC:8081/basicManage, 
healthUrl=http://PC-PC:8081/basicManage/health, serviceUrl=http://PC-PC:8081/basicManage] at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:8999/api/applications]): 
I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8999/api/applications": Connection refused: connect; 
nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I didn't know why. But after a moment again, the client application'status was UP again! I didn't do anything! I was very confused after this. The journal about the spring boot admin ui showed like this:

[image]

The configuration of my admin server application is like this:

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8999
spring.application.name=Spring Boot Admin Web
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:${server.port}
```

**pom.xml of Maven**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.boot.admin.version>1.4.6</spring.boot.admin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.admin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.admin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The configuration of my admin client application is like this:

**application.properties**

```
## EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION
server.context-path=/basicManage
server.port=8081

# spring boot admin
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8999

spring.application.name=ERP Basic Management Module
```

**pom.xml of Maven**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <spring.boot.admin.version>1.4.6</spring.boot.admin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.admin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get a connection refused, the server can't establish a network connection. This is either because of your network failing or the maximum connection limit is reached or a couople of other reaseons.

[Fallacies of distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing)

1. **The network is reliable.**
2. Latency is zero.
3. Bandwidth is infinite.
4. The network is secure.
5. Topology doesn't change.
6. There is one administrator.
7. Transport cost is zero.
8. The network is homogeneous.